# My Angular component can't be used anywhere else but app.component.html - everywhere else it's an error

Tags: angular

I created a standard Angular component with Input fields. I can use it like this in app.component.html without issue:

```
<app-my-component [firstInput]="inputValue1"
                    [secondInput]="inputValue2"></app-my-component>
```

However, I also want to use it in many other places in the app. I've created another component that I want to use 'my-component' too but when I put it in there it shows this error highlight in HTML:

```
'app-my-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-my-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-my-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I do have that component in the declarations array of NgModule in the app.module.ts - it works in app.component.html after all but for some reason anywhere else it doesn't.

Comment: It needs to be declared in the same module as your other component.

Comment: You're right. I can't believe I haven't noticed it was missing from declarations. Thank you very much